# Is $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)=\mathbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, quotient-spaces

> Is $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)=\mathbb R$?

I am reading Artin's Algebra and trying to analyze quotient rings. In one example he shows that $\mathbb Z[i]/(i-2) \cong \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$, example $11.4.5$. Very cool.

Now, I am trying to do a similar analyzing to see what $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)$ is.

We know $x^2-2$ is reducible and $x^2-2=(x-\sqrt 2)(x+\sqrt 2)$. **So, is it true I that I can write $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)=\mathbb R[x]/(x-\sqrt 2)(x+\sqrt 2)$?**

Also, I presume that since the canoncial map $\mathbb R[x] \to \mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)$ where $x \mapsto \sqrt 2$, then we can write $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)=\mathbb R[\sqrt 2]$. But since $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R[\sqrt 2]=\mathbb R$

Comment: You are mis-using the words "canonical map" here. One reason to know it is not "canonical" in any sense is that you don't know whether to send $x\mapsto \sqrt{2}$ or $x\mapsto -\sqrt{2}.$ The canonical map $R\to R/I$ in general sends $a$ to $a+I$.

Comment: But no, $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)$ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb R$. It is isomorphic to $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. I'll let you guess that isomorphism.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[x] / (x - \sqrt{2}) \cong \mathbb{R}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is it $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2) \cong \mathbb R[\sqrt 2]\times \mathbb R[-\sqrt 2] \cong\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

Take the homomorphism:

$$\mathbb R[x]\to \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\\
p(x)\mapsto (p(\sqrt{2}),p(-\sqrt{2}))$$

The kernel of this homomorphism is the set of $p$ such that $p(\sqrt{2})=p(-\sqrt{2})=0$, which means the $p$ which are divisible by $x^2-2$.

So the factor map: $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)\to\mathbb R\times\mathbb R.$ is one-to-one.

Now you just have to prove that this map is onto.

Comment: What's wrong with this: If we have the map $\mathbb R[x]\to \mathbb R$ where $x \mapsto \sqrt 2$, then the kernel of the map is $(x^2−2)$. Doesn't that mean $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2) \cong \mathbb R$?

Comment: The kernel of your map is not $(x^2-2)$, because $x-\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb R[x]$ is in the kernel of that map. You need that $\sqrt{2}$ *and* $-\sqrt{2}$ are roots of $p$ to ensure that $x^2-2$ divides $p$. However, if you were talking about $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$, you'd be correct that any rational polynomial with $\sqrt{2}$ as a root has $x^2-2$ as a factor.

Comment: I'm relearning this stuff and have decided to revisit this question. I've now learned that $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 -1) \cong \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$ as rings where the multiplicative operation is given by $(a_0, a_1)(b_0, b_1)=(a_0b_0+2a_1b_1, a_0b_1+a_1b_0)$. However, I noticed that this is like multiplying elements of the form $a_0+a_1\sqrt{2}$ since $(a_0+a_1\sqrt{2})(b_0+b_1\sqrt{2})=(a_0b_0+2a_1b_1)+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)\sqrt{2}$. So, is $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 -1) \cong \{a +b \sqrt{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb R^2\}$?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2--1)\cong \mathbb R^2 \equiv \mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2).$ So they are isomorphic, but the isomorphism is complicated. @AlJebr

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if you have a principal domain $A$ and $p,q$ two relatively prime elements, $A/(pq)$ is isomorphic to $A/p\times A/q$.

You have quotients map $f_p:A\rightarrow A/p$ and $f_q$. $(f_p,f_q):A\rightarrow A/p\times A/q$

suppose that $(f_p(l),f_q(l))=0$, you can write $up+vq=1,u,v\in A$ this implies that $l-upl+vql$ since $f_p(l)=0, l=ap$, $l=bq$ implies $l=upbq+vqap=pq(ub+av)$, this implies that $l\in (pq)$ this implies that the kernel of $(f_p,f_q)$ is $(pq)$.

Let $x,y\in A$, $x=upx+vqx, y=upy+vqy, f_p(vqx+upy)=f_p(x), f_q(upy+vqy)=f_q(y)$ this implies that $(f_p,f_q)$ is surjective and $(f_p,f_q)$ induces an isomorphism $A/(pq)\rightarrow A/p\times A/q$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to elaborate on what we get when we have $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2)$. I know the elements are cosets, and an element looks like $f+I$. But what exactly is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is a principal domain since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, $X-\sqrt2$ and $X+\sqrt2$ are relatively prime, $(X-\sqrt2)(X+\sqrt2)=X^2-2$.

Comment: If we have the map $\mathbb R[x] \to \mathbb R$ where $x \mapsto \sqrt 2$, then the kernel of the map is $(x^2-2)$. Doesn't that mean $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-2) \cong \mathbb R$?

Comment: the kernel is $(X-\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Ahh Ok. I see now.

Comment: Is there a sufficient condition for $\mathbb R[x]/I$ to be an integral domain?

Comment: yes, since you have prime and bezout

Comment: Specifically, since $\mathbb R[x]$ is s PID, you need $I=(p(x))$ for some irreducible polynomial $p\in \mathbb R[x].$ These are only the liner $p(x)=x+c$ and quadratics $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$ where $a^2-4b<0.$ @AlJebr